# How to bind Python to C++ code that includes Jsoncpp?

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, jsoncpp

Working on a code that enables Python to call a C++ code compiled into shared library file (`.so` file) via Python's `ctypes` module, using the standard `ctypes.CDLL` method. The C++ code performs the numerical calculations and the Python code mainly serves as a controller and performs data analysis. Everything worked fine. However, as soon as I included `jsoncpp` library in C++ code, Python started to complain about undefined symbol errors such as `undefined symbol: _ZN4Json5ValueaSES0_` etc. I used `jsoncpp` library in C++ mainly to export data to a JSON file. Having searched the internet for a while, it appears this hasn't been discussed that much. Any idea how to handle this?

Comment: How do you compile the C++ code?

Comment: With a -ljsoncpp flag. The C++ code compiles successfully and delivers the desired JSON file. As soon as I called it from Python, the error occured.

Comment: What platform and compiler are you using?

Comment: It is on Ubuntu 16.04. ```CC=g++```
```CFLAGS=-I. -std=c++11``` ```$(CC) -c -Wall -fPIC -ljsoncpp testcode.cpp -o testcode.o  $(CFLAGS)```
 ```$(CC) -shared -o testcode.so testcode.o```. Version of g++ is ```5.4.0 20160609```. The Python version is 3.7 and the ```.so``` file is called Python via ```ctypes.CDLL("./testcode.so")```. When C++ is not using Jsoncpp, Python call executes normally. (Sorry, can't format codes in comment).

Comment: `-ljsoncpp` is a linker flag, so it's required in the 2nd command (if present it's ignored in the 1st). Anyway the question has nothing to do with *Python* (and related).

Comment: @ CristiFati. Before I figured out this linker flag issue, I didn't know if the problem had anything to do with Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, looks like the solution is to also include `-ljsoncpp` flag while compiling towards the shared `.so` file:

```
 $(CC) -shared -o testcode.so testcode.o -ljsoncpp
```